# Jboss EAP 7.0+Hibernate 5+Azure DB: DataSource returns SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, azure-sql-database, datasource

me and my team are developing for the very first time into Azure environment.
We are developing a 3 tier application and we're having issues with our BackEnd WebApp.

This app contains a DataLayer.jar configured with Hibernate 5.0.3 that points at Jboss EAP 7.0 DataSource

Our main problem is that, after 1 or 2 hours from the deploy (and clearly even after a long no use time) we start to receive errors like these:

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.j

WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-32) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-32) Connection reset
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@3a0def4b
WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.NoTxConnectionListener] (default task-2) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.NoTxConnectionListener@253f452d[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@32b71315 connection handles=1 lastReturned=1515136631568 lastValidated=1515138292439 lastCheckedOut=1515138302331 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@31187fff mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@47d017b9[pool=MyDataBase]]: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset

[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) Connection reset
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@234ed87d
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-4) IJ031040: Connection is not associated with a managed connection: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk8.WrappedConnectionJDK8@7dfde86
[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.NoTxConnectionListener] (default task-5) IJ000305: Connection error occured: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.NoTxConnectionListener@2c142405[state=NORMAL managed connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@e35bc5 connection handles=1 lastReturned=1515137178316 lastValidated=1515137178316 lastCheckedOut=1515137180529 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@31187fff mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool@47d017b9[pool=MyDataBase]]: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
```

If we disable and re-enable the deployed war it turns back to normal till the 1/2 hours mentioned before

We searched a lot but and made lot of modifications to our project, but still we have the same problem.

actually our **Jboss EAP 7.0 DataSource** configuration is like this:

```
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mydb" pool-name="MyDataBase" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://myserverdatabaseonazure:1433;databaseName=mydbname</connection-url>
                <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                <driver>sql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>100</min-pool-size>
                    <initial-pool-size>500</initial-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>850</max-pool-size>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>myuser@mydomain</user-name>
                    <password>mypassword</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>select current_timestamp</check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>30000</background-validation-millis>
                    <use-fast-fail>false</use-fast-fail>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

Our  **Persistence.xml on Hibernate 5.0.3**  is like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="smdatasource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mydb</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>modelsclassesarehere</class>
    <properties>
      <!--com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver-->
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="mydefaultschema"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="on_close"/>
      <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
      <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

*Edit: we upgraded sqljdbc library module too on Jboss, we put the last sqljdbc42.jar instead the default one.*

Answer (score 1):

Those errors zero I have seen them when connections have been killed. They sometimes occur during big workloads, when connections haven been idle for a while and when throttling occurs. You should wrap all your SQL Commands on a retry logic due to this type of errors and some transient errors that are natural to Azure SQL Database. Please learn more about transient errors and retry logic on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/transient-fault-handling) article.